# KD_raj185 rpgle code in as400 try this please

Tags: rpgle

1. an assignment operator is expected with the eval operation
2. a semi colon is not specified at the end of a free format statement
3. the name or indicator is not defined
4. the compiler cannot determine how the program can end try this please

hope its clear for issue

Comment: Please provide your code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#1 & 2 are pretty evident, the error tells the line number in the source with the problem, just fix it. #3 is pretty evident as well, the error will tell you the name of the variable that is not defined.

#4 is the only one that is a bit tricky if you haven't seen it before. The compiler did not find a return from the main procedure, and also no place that *INLR is set on. Either of those things will fix that one.

Odds are that you just included some typos in your code. Please don't paste the entire source and error listing, just read the errors, and go find someone in your company that can tell you where in the source listing to find the errors. Or if you are using RDi, you could just click on the error, and it will take you directly to the problem.